# Como faço para alternar jogadores nesse código em java script?

Tags: javascript

Ola, estou criando um jogo, que quem acertar o numero ganha, porém gostaria de adicionar para os player botar os nomes, e cada vez que o outro player fosse jogar, aparecer por exemplo "É a vez de player dois"...

Teria como fazer isso?
Muito obrigado!

Código que já fiz:

```js
alert("Acerte o numero entre 1 e 100 para ganhar!");

var ValorMinino = 1;
var ValorMaximo = 100;
var Aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var Valor = 0;
Valor = Number(Valor);
var Partida = 1;
var jogadorAtual = 1;

while (Partida == 1) {

    Valor = prompt("Jogador " + jogadorAtual + " digite um valor entre " + ValorMinino + " e " + ValorMaximo);
    var Valor2 = Valor
    
    if (Valor2 > Aleatorio){
        ValorMaximo = Valor2}

    if (Valor2 < Aleatorio){
        ValorMinino = Valor2}

    if (Valor2 == Aleatorio) {
        Partida = Partida + 1
    }

    if (jogadorAtual == 1){
        jogadorAtual = jogadorAtual + 1
        }
    else{
        jogadorAtual = jogadorAtual - 1
    }
}
alert("O jogador que ganhoi foi quem digitou o número " + Aleatorio );
```

Comment: beleza irei fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desse jeito acho que resolve o seu problema.

```
    <script>
    alert("Erre o numero entre 1 e 100 para ganhar!");

var ValorMinino = 1;
var ValorMaximo = 100;
var Aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var Valor = 0;
Valor = Number(Valor);
var Partida = 1;

var jogador1 = prompt("Informe o nome do primeiro Jogador");
var jogador2 = prompt("Informe o nome do segundo jogador");
var jogadorAtual;
var contador = 0;
while (Partida == 1) {
    if((contador%2)==0){
        jogadorAtual = jogador1;
    }else{
        jogadorAtual = jogador2;
    }
    contador++;
    Valor = prompt("Jogador " + jogadorAtual + " digite um valor entre " + ValorMinino + " e " + ValorMaximo);
    if(Valor<=ValorMinino || Valor>=ValorMaximo){
        alert("Valor inválido, escolha um número entre "+ValorMinino + " e " + ValorMaximo);
    }else{
        var Valor2 = Valor

        if (Valor2 > Aleatorio){
            ValorMaximo = Valor2}

        if (Valor2 < Aleatorio){
            ValorMinino = Valor2}

        if (Valor2 == Aleatorio) {
            Partida = Partida + 1
        }

    }
}
alert("O jogador "+ jogadorAtual+" perdeu, digitou o número " + Aleatorio );
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado.